# Elevated Permissions in ADO.NET

Tags: sharepoint, ado.net

I was given job to check for possible ways of acces to SharePoint list from client-side desktop application and after some research I found that ADO.NET will be, in my opinion, best for that task. 
Some code:

```
            MySiteDataContext context = new MySiteDataContext(new Uri("http://MySite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc"));

            context.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("login", "password", "domain");

            List<MyListItem> list = context.MyList.ToList<MyListItem>();

            grid.ItemsSource = list;
```

And here is my question: Is there any way to run code like this with elevated permissions to read lists (even if credentials I gave don't have rights). Most probably there is no chance to do that because it's client-side, but I want to ensure that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.U can write your code in a seperate method.
2.Then call that method in the place where u need,like SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(MethodName);
```

Comment: That's work but for server-side appliactions and I was talking about client-side where I am forced to use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client classes and. For example WPF or WinForms Application running on my PC in my home and I want to get list from SP site that isn't running on localhost.

Comment: You can use something like this.
using (Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ClientContext ctx = new Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ClientContext("http://sharepointserver")){

ctx.AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ClientAuthenticationMode.Default

}

Comment: Nice idea but I got 401 error (unauthorized). This can't be done because of security issuses on client-side. Anyway thanks for try.